# DEBUG mode is not called if project is in Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

If the project is in Swift DEBUG mode is called and return google ads test ID. But if the project is in Objective-C DEBUG mode is not called and return real ads ID. Any help is appreciated.

```
#if DEBUG
    return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294"
#else
    return "ca-app-pub-*****/*****"
```

Comment: Do you have the DEBUG flag in Objective-C? In `Build Settings/Apple Clang - Preprocessing/Preprocessor Macros`

Comment: Two different compilers uses two different compilation options. You should setup both.

Comment: Where to set  compilation options from? @Cy-4AH

Comment: In Build Settings/Apple Clang - Preprocessing/Preprocessor Macros DEBUG flag is set. @Larme